override the core acl without overriding any of core file
<type name="Magento\PurchaseOrderGraphQl\Model\Filters\CompanyPurchaseOrders">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="allowedResources" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="view_purchase_orders_for_company" xsi:type="string">Magento_PurchaseOrder::view_purchase_orders_for_company</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

If i want to tell magento not to use above acl, use the one which i created in this case if i pass my new acl in the place of this "Magento_PurchaseOrder::view_purchase_orders_for_company" works? or it takes the newly created acl as another set of permission?
